# Can I combine the getting from an array with the creation of an array?

Tags: c#

Is there a way that I can refactor this code into one statement:

```
// Following line used referenced only once
public static Color[] TabBarBackgroundColor      = { greyEF, grey00, grey00 }; 

// Here's where it's referenced
Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]  = Styles.TabBarBackgroundColor[thc];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't initialize the static variable:

```
  Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]  = (new[]{ greyEF, grey00, grey00 })[thc];
```

or you don't even need array for values shown in the post:

```
  Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]  = thc == 0 ? greyEF : grey00;
```

If you do need to lazily initalize static variable:

```
 public static Color[] TabBarBackgroundColor = null;

  Current.Resources["TabBarBackgroundColor"]  = 
       (TabBarBackgroundColor == null ? 
             TabBarBackgroundColor = (new[]{ greyEF, grey00, grey00 }) :
             TabBarBackgroundColor)[thc];
```

Note that it look more like [refucktoring](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=refucktoring) and I'd not recommend doing so in code that someone else will ever need to read.